# Android jetpack navigation drawerlayout doesn't replace whole fragment on item selection toolbar still visible

Tags: android

How to setup drawer layout in toolbar of fragment, navigationUi.setupwithnavcontroller() expects activity.
I want to setup drawer layout in nested navigation graph.            Added action bar drawer toggle it works but changes the default drawer layout implementation.On selection of drawer menu item whole fragment is not replaced toolbar still appears

Comment: You can generate a new DrawerActivity which includes the navgraph and all fragment in latest android studio.

Comment: Can we use  two activity  in navgraph,i hv to set drawerlayout in nested graph

Comment: I have never tried with two activities. But you can check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717028/how-do-i-link-multiple-activities-in-android-navigation-editor

Comment: I referred this but the point of navigation graph is to use single fragment.thank you for your time